# parse query on users objectId comes up blank?

Tags: php, parse-platform

im trying to get users objectId so i can attach a link to the image.
when i try to use

```
href="other-user-profile.php?userID='$user->get('objectId')'"
```

in the hover over it says mywebsite.com/user-profile&userID=
This what ive tried

```
<?php
$nearDeliveries = $items->getNearDeliveries();
foreach ($nearDeliveries as $user):
$avatarUrl = 'images/default.jpg';
if ($user->get('avatar')) {
    $avatarUrl = $user->get('avatar')->getURL();
}
$stars = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < (int)$user->rating; $i++) {
    $stars .= '<img src="images/leaf-star.png" class="rate-star"  />';
}

echo '<li class="product-box">
    <div class="item-box">
    <a href="other-user-profile.php?userID='$user->get('objectId')'">
        <img src="' . $avatarUrl . '" class="product-image" />
     </div>
    <strong>' . $user->get('username') . '</strong>

    <span>
          <span>' . $stars . '</span>
  </span>
</li>';
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: You're missing string concatenation operators (`.`) around `$user->get('objectId')`

Comment: <a href="other-user-profile.php?userID='. $user->get('objectId') . '"> same

Comment: <a href="other-user-profile.php?userID='. $user->get('objectId') .'"> same thing maybe it has to do with permissions im thinking idk

Comment: So it sounds like `$user->get('objectId')` is returning `null` or an empty string. Have you tried `var_dump($user->get('objectId'))` to see if it has anything in it?

Comment: var_dump($user->get('objectId')) returns null

Comment: Well there's your problem then. Perhaps `objectId` isn't the right thing to be getting? I don't know parse well enough to tell you what it should actually be...

Comment: ya im not sure what else to try to get. Thanks ill keep messing around with it.

Comment: ANSWER - <a href="other-user-profile.php?userID='.$user->getObjectId().'">

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="other-user-profile.php?userID='.$user->getObjectId().'">
```

Comment: Glad you answered your own question :-) but can you add an explanation to your answer to say why this worked?

Comment: Good to see you got it figured out.